# Password box ToolTip not appearing

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox and wondering how do I properly implement the tooltip?

```
<PasswordBox    
    ToolTip="To Enable, please enter SMTP server and port"
    x:Name="Password" 
    Framework:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="true"
    Framework:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    IsEnabled="False" />
```

I added in the ToolTip Text but the tool tip doesn't appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default a `Control` has to be enabled for `ToolTip`s to show. Try wrapping the `PasswordBox` inside an element that has no visual, and put the `ToolTip` on that:

```
<Border ToolTip="To Enable, please enter SMTP server and port">
    <PasswordBox x:Name="Password" 
                 Framework:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="true"
                 Framework:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 IsEnabled="False" />                
</Border>
```

Another way to make it work is to use the [`ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showondisabled(v=vs.110).aspx) attached property. This is the better solution:

```
<PasswordBox ToolTip="To Enable, please enter SMTP server and port"
             x:Name="Password" 
             Framework:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="true"
             Framework:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
             VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
             IsEnabled="False"
             ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" />
```

Comment: Great answer! Option 1 worked, ToolTipService didn't quite work.

Comment: Ahh I know what happened. It does work but my Password box has a Focusable="{Binding EmailEnabled}" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding EmailEnabled}". It prevents anything from being entered into the password box until EmailEnabled is set to true. Thanks! I removed focusable and ishittestvisible with IsEnabled.